# How to get number of days in moment-jalaali on NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

The question is *How to get number of days in  moment-jalaali package on NodeJS?*. I cannot find any `numOfDay` or something like this on [their API](https://github.com/jalaali/moment-jalaali) in js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution which comes to my mind for jDate `m` is:

```
let num_day = m.endOf('jMonth').jDayOfYear() - m.startOf('jMonth').jDayOfYear() + 1;
```

You should be aware that the following code does not work properly:

```
let first_day = m.startOf('jMonth');
let end_day = m.endOf('jMonth');
let num_day = end_day.jDayOfYear() - first_day.jDayOfYear() + 1;
```

Because `m.startOf` and `m.endOf` change the `m`, then as `m` is referenced in each assignment, you will get `1` as the above code result for all possible `m` values.